# MySQL Stored Procedure not working with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have an mysql stored procedure where with one input, that works great. Now i need two inputs, but its not working and i cant figure out whats wrong.

Here is my store procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`multilager`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `lagerbeholdning_alle`(IN `bruker_gruppe` INT, IN `bruker_gruppe2` INT)
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
           CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN lagerbeholdning.lok_id = ', lagerbeholdning.lok_id,
                  ' THEN antall END) `', lagerbeholdning.lok_id, '`'))
    INTO @sql
    FROM lagerbeholdning
    INNER JOIN lokasjoner ON lagerbeholdning.lok_id = lokasjoner.lok_id
    WHERE bruker_gruppe_ref = bruker_gruppe;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT produkt_id, prod_navn, kat_navn, size_navn, farge_navn, prod_bilde, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM lagerbeholdning
                     INNER JOIN produkter ON produkt_id = prod_id
                     INNER JOIN produkt_kategorier on prod_kat_id = kat_id
                     INNER JOIN produkt_sizes on prod_size_id = size_id
                     INNER JOIN produkt_farger on prod_farge_id = farge_id
                     WHERE produkter.prod_bruker_gruppe = bruker_gruppe2
                     GROUP BY produkt_id');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

If i call the procedure:

```
CALL lagerbeholdning_alle(3,3)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unknown column 'bruker_gruppe2' in 'where clause'
```

How can i use the bruker_gruppe2 parameter in the last where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT` will treat it as normal text and will pass it to query without replacing with value.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT produkt_id, prod_navn, kat_navn, size_navn, farge_navn, prod_bilde, ', @sql, ' 
       FROM lagerbeholdning
       INNER JOIN produkter ON produkt_id = prod_id
       INNER JOIN produkt_kategorier on prod_kat_id = kat_id
       INNER JOIN produkt_sizes on prod_size_id = size_id
       INNER JOIN produkt_farger on prod_farge_id = farge_id
       WHERE produkter.prod_bruker_gruppe = ', bruker_gruppe2, '
       GROUP BY produkt_id');
```

Now it should be replaced correctly.